# Jenkins out of nowhere starts failing with sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: jenkins

No system changes, just starts failing with this error each time it tries to install a gem from `bundle install`, though I don't even see why sudo is being called since gems are installed in local rvm dir...

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Anyone ever seen this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For jenkins to install gems, he needs to be in the rvm group:

In debian, that means:

```
sudo adduser jenkins rvm
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

That worked for me at least.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Jenkins server was asking for the password because it was trying to bundle gems for the system, because for some reason the job was no longer running with rvm environment.  Simply choosing this option again stopped job from throwing this error. :)