# jenkins fails while restarting my sql "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified Sorry, try again."

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I just configured jenkins and in the pre-build steps i am trying to restart jenkins but i end up with the following error

```
Commencing build of Revision c5b9f8daac092efc5396d80f568a2cf89ae8b697 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision c5b9f8daac092efc5396d80f568a2cf89ae8b697 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
No change to record in branch origin/HEAD
No change to record in branch origin/master
[webapp] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5215632082686866774.sh
+ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I googled and saw some answers at [Jenkins out of nowhere starts failing with sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263367/jenkins-out-of-nowhere-starts-failing-with-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-p)

But unfortunately that didn't help me

My /etc/sudoers looks like this

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Answer (score 4):

By adding the following:
`Defaults:username !authenticate`
to your `/etc/sudoers`
you should not get the error but this username will be accessible without asking for a password

Answer (score 3):

The "no tty present" error indicates that you have the 'requiretty' setting in your sudoers file. In your case, it is probably in /etc/sudoers.d.
Once this line is there, it does not matter what group you are in - sudo will require a tty whenever it is executed.

To get around this, you need to either remove (or comment out) the requiretty line in the configuration file, or add a line to exclude your user from the requiretty setting. You can see how to do that here:
[Disable requiretty per user](https://serverfault.com/questions/111064/sudoers-how-to-disable-requiretty-per-user)

Comment: I'm having this problem and I don't have the requiretty setting in either /etc/sudoers or in any file in /etc/sudoers.d (which contains only a README file with comments).

Comment: The default requiretty value depends on the linux distro you are using. Add the line "Defaults:username !requiretty" to your sudoers file and replace username with the actual username.

Comment: Thanks @Barak.  That solved it for me.  I'm using Ubuntu and my `man sudoers` says that requiretty is off by default, but I guess it wasn't because explicitly disabling it as you suggested fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the "id" command and paste the output. Only if you are in admin group then you don't need password but for all other even though you have access but you need to type the sudo password. In this case sudo doesn't have a tty to ask for the password and hence the error.

One solution could be, don't use sudo only for mysql restart, instead run the entire script as sudo "sudo {your script path}"  in this case sudo will have the terminal to ask for the password.

Comment: my id command returns this

uid=108(jenkins) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup),111(admin)

i think the user jenkins is in admin group so sudo is not the problem. When you say "In this case sudo doesn't have a tty to ask for the password and hence the error" what exactly does that mean? How do i add tty?