# Trying to update ruby ruby-2.0.0-p247 with jewelry box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is saying:
Error running '__smf_try_sudo sm get head'

What do I need to do?

The whole thing is:

```
[2013-10-02 14:11:27] requirements_smf_update_system
requirements_smf_update_system () 
{ 
    __rvm_log_command sm_get_head "Updating SMF" __smf_try_sudo sm get head || return $?;
    if [[ "${#required_extension_sets[@]}" -gt 0 ]]; then
        __rvm_log_command sm_install_extension_sets "Installing/updating extension sets: ${required_extension_sets[*]}" requirements_smf_install_extension_sets "${required_extension_sets[@]}" || return $?;
    fi
}
current path: /
command(2): requirements_smf_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247
Updating SMF.
Error running '__smf_try_sudo sm get head',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1380715887_ruby-2.0.0-p247/sm_get_head.log
```

Comment: Well, what is contained in the `/usr/local/rvm/log/1380715887_ruby-2.0.0-p247/sm_get_head.log` file?

Comment: forgot to add, it's this:

[2013-10-02 14:11:27] __smf_try_sudo
__smf_try_sudo () 
{ 
    if [[ -w "$( __rvm_which sm )" ]]; then
        "$@";
    else
        __rvm_try_sudo "$@";
    fi
}
current path: /
command(4): __smf_try_sudo sm get head
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: Then maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408877/jenkins-fails-while-restarting-my-sql-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-progr

Comment: No, that ain't the case. That line is not existing in my sudoers file. Any other idea how to bypass it?

Comment: In the end I tried it with rvm itself in the console... That told me to run:
WARNING: you have 'rvm_configure_env' in /etc/rvmrc, run the following to fix:

      sudo sed -i'' -e "/rvm_configure_env=.*\/opt\/sm/d" /etc/rvmrc
      rvm autolibs smf

That fixed it!!!

Comment: @JahnSchlosser - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn - I accepted the post you made as the correct answer! I did check the green mark. Hope thats enough. Next time I know how to do it directly! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> In the end I tried it with rvm itself in the console... That told me
> to run:
>
> WARNING: you have 'rvm_configure_env' in /etc/rvmrc, run the
> following to fix: sudo sed -i'' -e "/rvm_configure_env=.*/opt/sm/d" /etc/rvmrc rvm autolibs smf
>
> That fixed it!!!

~ answer per [Jahn Schlosser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2838565/jahn-schlosser)